# Going crazy! MySQL update not working on one table, working fine on another

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

For no obvious reason (to me..) I can't do an UPDATE on a table anymore in MySQL. Version is :

```
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.29-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
```

What I did was the following :
I added a new table to an existing database. The table looks like this :

```
CREATE TABLE `drawdata` (
  `year` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `left1` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `left2` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  ...
  ...
  `left31` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `left32` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`year`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

When I do the next query in the MySQL CLI, I get

```
update drawdata set year=2017;

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

And nothing has been updated. (a SELECT proves that). Can't do it either using phpMyAdmin.
No errors, no warnings. Nothing in the mysql.log either.

But, I *can* do the exact same statement on another table, that also has the column year as primary key.

Just found out that doing an INSERT on the table works, and if I do an UPDATE after that, the UPDATE also works.
When I do a `DELETE FROM drawdata`, clearing all data from the table, and then do the UPDATE statement again, the same problem is back: 0 rows affected, 0 matched.

So, I guess, the ultimate question is :
Why can't I do an UPDATE on an empty table/column, whereas I *can* do this on another table ?

Any suggestions, please ?

Comment: @Mureinik `year=2017` is not a condition. It's the update to do.

Comment: You want to update an empty table ? If it isn't empty then it would fail.. the PK is on year column which you want to update with 2017 for all rows in the table (if any). That would work only if you have one row in the table. Can you give us an example of the data in the table ?

Comment: I don't understand what your intentions are. I don't see any filter in your SQL query, why don't you use a 'WHERE' statement? I mean, I'd do 'UPDATE drawdata SET left1="something" WHERE year=2017 '

Comment: "Just found out that doing an INSERT on the table works, and if I do an UPDATE after that, the UPDATE also works."......... you answered your own question I think.

Comment: I think the OP is new at databases and doesn't know the concepts. So many things wrong here. I would suggest the OP to read a good tutorial, not the one he's using now.

Comment: True. I think I know what I'm doing wrong. This is an old project, and I must have made sure the PK was already filled. Must have forgotten that when creating (and not inserting anything in) this new table. Will try it out and update this question accordingly.. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: Remeber if you have year as `PK` you will have only 1 row that can eventually have year equal to 2017, so an update to update all records with 2017 could also result in an error if you don't allow duplicates.

Comment: That's not the intention. The rest of the columns are people's names participtaing in a tournament in a given year.

Answer (score 0):

Silly me.

At least my nickname was chosen well....

After INSERTing the value 2017 in column year, I was able to do UPDATEs on all columns. Works as designed. Now I need to...

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to update an empty table. That's why your UPDATE statement never do anything.

Other thing to keep in mind, your UPDATE statement try to modified all year columns to 2017, but this columns it's PK. You will have a PK conflict, remember PK's definition:

> The PRIMARY KEY constraint uniquely identifies each record in a
>   database table.
>
> Primary keys must contain UNIQUE values.
>
> A primary key column cannot contain NULL values.
>
> Most tables should have a primary key, and each table can have only
>   ONE primary key.

Comment: I see. The statement I showed was just (wrongly) intended to fill only the PK.